# basic set of operation to transform square matrixes

Tags: matrices

There is any finite set of operations to transform any square matrix to any other square matrix (of the same order) ? If there isn't, can we construct a stable sub group with such property?

Comment: Couldn't you guarantee a matrix inverse by adding $(1-\det x)I$ where I is the identity matrix. With an inverse you can convert a matrix to the identity matrix and then convert to any other matrix through identity multiplication.

Comment: Do you mean only *unary* operations? Since if you do, then this is trivially impossible, because all this operations with all compositions form a countable set, while the set of matrices has strictly greater cardinality.

Comment: This is only interesting if some restriction is placed on the "operations" allowed.  For example, consider the operations that alter entries of a matrix to different values.  These operations allow any matrix to be transformed to any other (of the same row and column dimensions).